# A convenient way to accept a fixed length number with decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I need to accept a simple decimal value string from a input box.
The length of the input is fixed to 5 digits so it is allowed to accept only 5 digit value.

But if the length  of integer part is 5, it should be able to accommodate at least 2 more decimal points or should at least  accommodate  2 decimal digits (excluding the decimal separator ) at any time.But the length of the integer part should not exceed 5 digits.

I thought used the following way :

```
//co2-weight is the class of input field
//by default the max-length and size is 6
$( '.co2-weight' ).keyup(function() {
      if($(this).val().indexOf('.')>1)
          {
          $('.co2-weight').attr('size','9');
          $('.co2-weight').attr('maxlength','9'); 
          }
      else
          {
          $('.co2-weight').attr('size','6');
          $('.co2-weight').attr('maxlength','6');
          }       
    });
```

But again here it need to check the length of integer part again and set it to 5.
Is there any shorter or convenient way ?

**UPDATE:**

The basic problem was to dynamically adjust the length in proper cases which are missing in the answers.

Comment: So basically you want to allow 12345.12 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code, which will not allow:

- more than 5 integer digits, nor
- more than 2 decimal digits, nor
- more than one decimal point, nor
- any other character than digits or decimal point

It also applies the attribute changes dependent on whether there is a decimal point.

It responds to the `input` event, as there are ways of changing the contents without the `keyup` event firing (e.g. through context menu, mouse,or other device).

```js
$( '.co2-weight' ).on('input', function() {
    var good = $(this).val()
        // remove bad characters and multiple points
        .replace(/[^\d.]|\.(?=.*\.)/, '')
        // remove any excess of 5 integer digits
        .replace(/^(\d{5})\d+/, '$1')
        // remove any excess of 2 decimal digits
        .replace(/(\.\d\d).+/, '$1');
    if (good !== $(this).val()) {
        // Only if something had to be fixed, update
        $(this).val(good);
    }
    var pointPos = good.indexOf('.');
    // Determine max size depending on presence of point
    var size = good.indexOf('.')>1 ? 8 : 6;
    // Use prop instead of attr
    $('.co2-weight').prop('size',size);
    $('.co2-weight').prop('maxlength',size);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input: <input class="co2-weight" size="6" maxlength="6">
```

Comment: Works great ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect case where you use [regular expressions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

In your case this is the regular expression pattern that you need `^([0-9]{0,5}(\.[0-9]{0,2}){0,1})$`

In javascript you would use it this way:

```
$(this).val().match(/^([0-9]{0,5}(\.[0-9]{0,2}){0,1})$/)
```

This line alone returns null if it does not find your match. An array of the matches if it does find a match.

If you need to test out this regular expression use https://regex101.com/

Comment: yes, this implies the absence of other trailing spaces at the end though (that's what the $ at the end of the regex is). you can trim the string before testing it if you are afraid that might be a problem!

Answer (score 0):

Using [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) you can validate the format of the input like the following example ...

```js
// regular expression to allow 12345.12
var regExp = new RegExp(/^\d{1,5}\.?\d{0,2}$/);

// initialize form elements
$('.valid').hide();
$('.invalid').hide();
$('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

$('.co2-weight').keyup(function() {

  // on keyup validate against regular expression
  if (regExp.test($(this).val())) {
    $('.valid').show();
    $('.invalid').hide();
    $('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.valid').hide();
    $('.invalid').show();
    $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});

$('.form').submit(function() {
  
  // alert to show input was valid
  alert('submitted');
});
```

```css
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Type something in the input to see if submit button become enable</p>

<form class="form">
  <input type="text" class="co2-weight">
  <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>

<p class="valid">Input format is valid</p>
<p class="invalid">Input format must be <= 99999.99</p>
```

Comment: @joeyrohan after reading your question again an again i think i get it ... you want a max-length of 5 at first. If the input value is 5 digits you THEN want to expend the max-length to 8 (5 digit, 1 dot, 2 decimals) is that right?